# is it possible to send custom metrics using metricbeats?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat, elastic-apm

I have a python application from which i want to send some custom metrics to my elastic search. An example use case can be when a user does the delete data operation on the application (and this would not be an api call). I am already using elastic-APM to send real user metrics but is there anyway i can also send lots of other custom metrics like the one i just shared.
One way I found was using the ElasticSearch client but is it possible to use metricbeat instead(I read that metricbeat provides metric shipper for some services). What would be the difference if i would do so?

Comment: With the Python APM agent, you have the [possibility to send metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/metrics.html#prometheus-metricset) too

Comment: got it thanks. is there anyway i can add custom metrics generated above to the dashboard on apm metrics?

Comment: Not sure about adding to the dashboard. I think the default dashboard only uses metrics we build-in. But you could easily create your own dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/devguide/current/metricbeat-developer-guide.html) about creating custom metricsets in metricbeat.